# MYSQL function not working giving error result consisted of more than row

Tags: mysql

Dear Sir i write a MySQL function which not giving required values.When ever i call function it arise error of result consisted of more than row but i have more than one employees with same designation.Please help me to correct my code.Please find the enclosed attachment of error.I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSeiQ.jpg) will be thankful to you.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION get_usr_desg(USR_id INT)RETURNS VARCHAR(256) 
BEGIN
DECLARE U_DESG VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT"";

  SELECT usr_level  INTO   U_DESG
  FROM   tbl_usr_reg
  WHERE  usr_id =  USR_id;
  
  RETURN U_DESG;
  
END //;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I would not give parameters the same name as column names - even if you do have case sensitivity set.

Comment: So what is the solution of this problem please modify my code